# Integrating R from within Python .py scripts

Tags: python, r, integration

Comments on an earlier question suggest that you can use tools like `runipy` and `nbconvert` to take an `iPython/Jupyter` notebook and run it from the command line. Then, since notebooks support cell magics which support the R programming language, this could be one way to integrate `R` into `Python` code though admittedly I have not tested this yet.

If your code is already `.py` scripts that are run from the command line, is there a library or other means for writing sections of `R` code from within such Python code? If such a solution exists, does it require Python 2.x or Python 3.x or some other minimum version to support it?

UPDATES:

In a democratic community, we may not always agree but it never hurts to contribute to the discussion.  This question is posted here because the author believes that looking for standard and best practice approaches to integrating two coding languages should meet the help guidelines definition expressed with this bullet:

- "software tools commonly used by programmers."

As of this writing, a few votes were cast to close this.  If this question gets closed, I will accept the will of the community and attempt to re-post here even though to me, this feels like a programmer's question (as it facilitates the creation of code):  [Non-Programmers Beta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

On a related note:  a good suggestion was made in the comments, but investigations show that `rpy2` behaves very differently when activated as a cell magic then when activated in a `.py` script.  In case there are other options that might lead to cleaner integration, I had hoped to leave this question open to see what discussions and ideas it might lead to.

Comment: The python package you're looking for is `rpy2` - i'm not sure if its Python version specific.

Comment: I will look into that.  Thanks.